# How to show content from different ArrayLists in Recyclerview based on specific percentage?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have this simple recyclerview which shows content from an ArrayList. I want to show content from multiple ArrayLists based on the percentage. To put it simply: I want to put 2 ArrayLists in my code with different content. I want the Recyclerview to show content from both the arrayLists but not entirely. I want to set specific percentage for both the ArrayLists. Say, if I want to show 30% content from the ArrayList1 (with 10 items) and 70% content from ArrayList2 (with 10 items) then my recyclerview shoud show 3 items from ArrayList1 and 7 items from ArrayList2. (preferably in a random order).

MainActivity.java:

```
    private void initView() {
    // Initialize RecyclerView and set Adapter
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.scout_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    scoutArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ScoutAdapter(this,scoutArrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    createList();
}

private void createList() {
    //data to be shown in list
    scoutArrayList.add(new Scout( "Eren Jaeger" ,"Unranked" , "22" ));
    scoutArrayList.add(new Scout ( "Mikasa Ackermann" ,"Unranked" , "12" ) );
    scoutArrayList.add(new Scout ( "Armin Arlelt" ,"Unranked" , "0" ) );
    scoutArrayList.add(new Scout ( "Erwin Smith " , "Commander" , "Unknown" ) );
    scoutArrayList.add(new Scout ( "Levi Ackermann" , "Squad Captain" ,"~58" ) );
    scoutArrayList.add(new Scout ( "Hange Zoe" , "Commander" , "Unknown") );
    scoutArrayList.add(new Scout ( "Jean Kirschtein" , "Unranked" , "1" )   );
    scoutArrayList.add(new Scout ("Conny Springer", "Unranked" , "Unknown") );
    scoutArrayList.add(new Scout ("Sasha Braus","Unranked","1") );

}

private void createList2() {
    //data to be shown in list
    scoutArrayList2.add(new Scout( "Testname2" ,"rankvalue2" , "killscount2" ));
    scoutArrayList2.add(new Scout( "Testname2" ,"rankvalue2" , "killscount2" ));
    scoutArrayList2.add(new Scout( "Testname2" ,"rankvalue2" , "killscount2" ));
    scoutArrayList2.add(new Scout( "Testname2" ,"rankvalue2" , "killscount2" ));
    scoutArrayList2.add(new Scout( "Testname2" ,"rankvalue2" , "killscount2" ));
    scoutArrayList2.add(new Scout( "Testname2" ,"rankvalue2" , "killscount2" ));
    scoutArrayList2.add(new Scout( "Testname2" ,"rankvalue2" , "killscount2" ));
    scoutArrayList2.add(new Scout( "Testname2" ,"rankvalue2" , "killscount2" ));
    scoutArrayList2.add(new Scout( "Testname2" ,"rankvalue2" , "killscount2" ));
}
```

Adapter.java

```
   public ScoutAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Scout> scouts) {
    this.context = context;
    this.scouts = scouts;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ScoutHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false);
    return new ScoutHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ScoutHolder holder, int position) {
    Scout scout = scouts.get(position);
    holder.setDetails(scout);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return scouts.size();
}

public class ScoutHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView txtName, txtRank, txtKill;
    public ScoutHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtRank = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRank);
        txtKill = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtKill);
    }

    public void setDetails(Scout scout) {
        txtName.setText(scout.getName());
        txtRank.setText(String.format("Rank: %s", scout.getRank()));
        txtKill.setText(String.format("kill: %s", scout.getKillCount()));
    }
}
```

In the above code (MainActivity.java) there is this list named createList2(), I want to show 20% of the content from it......

Any solution to this?

Comment: You should make a third arraylist for the adapter. Put only the wanted items from first two in third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note how the number of elements is calculated when entering a percentage:

```
public static <T> List<T> getRandomValue (List<T> list, int percent){
        List<T> res = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < getIteration(percent, list.size()); i ++){
            res.add(list.get(i));
        }
        return res;
    }

public static int getIteration(int percent, int size){ // for example 97% will be 90%
        float res = (float) percent / 100 * size;
        return (int) res;
    }
```

```
public static <T> List<T> getViewList (List<T> firstList, int firstPercent, List<T> secondList, int secondPercent){
        List<T> first = getRandomValue(firstList, firstPercent);
        List<T> second = getRandomValue(secondList, secondPercent);
        first.addAll(second);
        return first;
    }
```

Please let me know if this works for you